# Using google APIs in the file system?

Tags: javascript, google-api, node-webkit

You have to set javascript origins in the Google Developer Console to allow certain origins to access the google apis. The problem is that I'm making an app that runs in the the node-webkit which uses the file:// protocol and google doesn't allow file:// to be a javascript origin.
Any work-arounds for this? I tried running a local http-server within node-webkit but that didn't work.

Comment: Why didn't a local HTTP server work?

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorials on how to do so and all i tried was useless :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use http://127.0.0.1/ or localhost URL to register API on Google Console but on your client side attach a listener to browser's window, So that when google api redirects to our end we could intercept that action and get `Authorization Code` from url. I have tried this on phonegap/cordova app, It works perfectly. Check the codebase for reference.

```
var authUrl = AUTH_URL + '?' +
'&client_id=' + options.client_id +
'&redirect_uri=' + options.redirect_uri +
'&response_type=code' +
'&scope=' + options.scopez +
'&approval_prompt=force';

//Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,closebuttoncaption="Close"');

authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
   var url = e.url;
   var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
   var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);
   //alert("code : " + JSON.stringify(code));
   if (code || error) {
   //Always close the browser when match is found
      console.log("code : " + code);
      console.log("Closing OAuth Window.");
      authWindow.close();
   }
   if (code) {
   //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
   OAuthService.getAccessTokenByCode(code[1]).then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
   }, function(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
   });
} else if (error) {
   //The user denied access to the app
      deferred.reject({
        error: error[1]
      });
    }
  });
```